# How to set up a build configuration for the debugger in vscode (using flavours in flutter with different entry points)?

Tags: flutter

I've set up flavours in Flutter. I've two entry points in to the application. `lib/main_dev.dart`
and `lib/main_prod.dart`. I'm not sure how to change the settings for my debugger to point to these entry points(currently it predictably points to `lib/main`). I'd imagine it's something in my `launch.json` file where I have to set up a new configuration.  I'm using vscode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can point to a different parts in the app with the key `"program"`.

For example in launch.json:

```
 {
            "name": "consumer-app",
            "cwd": "consumer-app",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "program": "lib/main_dev.dart"
        },
```